# Javascript Nested Objects/Arrays Code Reduction Problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object for a collection of video data called "CollectionData". It has 3 key/value pairs:

```
collectionData.title - a simple string value
collectionData.seriesData - an array
collectionData.progressData - an array
```

Each of the 2 array values are objects:

```
collectionData.seriesData[x].title
collectionData.seriesData[x].year
collectionData.seriesData[x].length
collectionData.seriesData[x].synopsis

collectionData.progressData[x].currentTime
collectionData.progressData[x].progress
```

To save from having to type out `collectionData.seriesData[x]` or `collectionData.progressData[x]`  every time to access the key's values I use a "pointer" into the object:

```
var p = collectionData.progressData[x];
```

I can then access the values of the keys by using `p.currentTime`, etc.

This works well if I want to replace a single key's value, i.e. `p.currentTime = 25`. However, if I want to replace the entire object's value, i.e. `p = {currentTime:25,progress=10}` the assignment operator does not evaluate the value of the variable `p` as a pointer into the object but as the pointer itself, therefore the object's value is not updated.

Is there a way to force the assignment operator to evaluate the variable `p` as a pointer or will I have to revert back to the full object name `collectionData.progressData[x]={currentTime:25,progress=10}`?

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and the new data which update the object.

```js
const
    data = [{ currentTime: 1, progress: 1 }],
    p = data[0];

Object.assign(p, { currentTime: 25, progress: 10 });

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina. Just what I needed. Works Great!